# Zend.DB: How do I group "orWhere()" clauses?

Tags: php, sql, zend-db

I've got a little task I've gotta handle, and while I *could* just use the `query()` function write out the SQL by hand, I'm ***really*** interested in learning about this.

**NOTE:** I'm pretty green on ZF (especially as a *framework*) .. I'm just using DB as a lib.

**Desired Outcome:**
What I'd like my sql to look like is something like:

```
SELECT name, phone, email 
FROM company 
WHERE name = 'Acme Anvil Corp' 
AND ( category1 = 'abc' 
      OR category3 = 'klm'
      OR category8 = 'xyz'
    )
```

**Where I've gotten so far:**

```
$select = $db 
            ->select() 
            ->from('company, array('name', 'phone', 'email'))
            ->where('name = ?', 'Acme Anvil Corp')
            ->limit(1);
```

After that, I'm buggered.
Adding a whole slew of `orWhere()`'s jut won't give the desired outcome.
How can I add a bunch of `orWhere()`'s in a collective grouping `()`?

**Alternatively**, I thought about trying to go the route of aiming for my SQL to look something more like:

```
SELECT c.name, c.phone, c.email 
FROM  (
        SELECT name, phone, email 
        FROM company
        WHERE category1 = 'abc' 
        OR category3 = 'klm'
        OR category8 = 'xyz'
      ) AS c
WHERE c.name = 'Acme Anvil Corp'
```

(I'm no SQL guru, so if there's a significant difference between these two, don't be shy on the feedback :)

Again, just unsure about how to approach that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate;

$select->where(array(
    // ...
    new Predicate\PredicateSet(
        array(
            new Predicate\Like('content', '%'.$searchstring.'%'),
            new Predicate\Like('title', '%'.$searchstring.'%'),
        ),
        Predicate\PredicateSet::COMBINED_BY_OR
    ),
    // ...
));
```

Also,

```
$predicate = new  \Zend\Db\Sql\Where();
$sql->where($predicate->greaterThan('filterColumn', '20'));
$sql->where($predicate->greaterThan('filterColumn', '30'), 'OR');
```

Comment: Thanks-a-Bunch for the quick response!!  While the first example looks a bit intimidating, the second looks promising. I'll toy with it.    If it's not too much, a complete example using my sample in the form of your second suggestion would really help me put this in context ... and it'd be **greatly** appreciated.  Again, thanks!